# kafka_2.12-2.3.0 broker shutdown in windows 10

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

below is the error i am getting in the console while trying to start the kafka server with kafka-server-start command in command prompt .

```
ERROR Error while creating log for kafka_example-0 in dir 
C:\Users\user11\Softwareskafka_2.12-2.3.0kafka_logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$resize$1(AbstractIndex.scala:188)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.resize(AbstractIndex.scala:174)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1(AbstractIndex.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.trimToValidSize(AbstractIndex.scala:240)

INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Stopping serving replicas in dir 
C:\Users\user11\Softwareskafka_2.12-2.3.0kafka_logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error while making broker the leader for  partition Topic: kafka_example; Partition: 0; Leader: None; AllReplicas: ;   InSyncReplicas:  in dir None (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while creating log for kafka_example-0 in dir C:\Users\user11\Softwareskafka_2.12-2.3.0kafka_logs
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$resize$1(AbstractIndex.scala:188)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.resize(AbstractIndex.scala:174)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1(AbstractIndex.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.trimToValidSize(AbstractIndex.scala:240)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.recover(LogSegment.scala:397)
    at kafka.log.Log.recoverSegment(Log.scala:493)
    at kafka.log.Log.recoverLog(Log.scala:608)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$loadSegments$3(Log.scala:568)

INFO Replica loaded for partition --from-beginning-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)

INFO [Partition --from-beginning-0 broker=0] --from-beginning-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)

INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-0 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)

INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-0, --from-beginning-0, Kafka_Example-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)

INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-0, --from-beginning-0, Kafka_Example-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)

INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-0,--from-beginning-0,Kafka_Example-0 and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory C:\Users\user11\Softwareskafka_2.12-2.3.0kafka_logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)

INFO Stopping serving logs in dir C:\Users\user11\Softwareskafka_2.12-2.3.0kafka_logs (kafka.log.LogManager)

 ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\Users\user11\Softwareskafka_2.12-2.3.0kafka_logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

on my local using java 8 version and above subject mentioned is kafka version.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Specifically, have you tried changing your `log.dirs` broker setting?